# Entity Framework is being restored via .NetFramework and not Core V2.0 which is my projects framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When downloading Entity Framework I am getting the error

> Package 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' was restored using '.NetFramework,
>   version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework ".NETCoreApp,
>   Version=v2.0' This package may not be fully compatible with your
>   project

The reason this is an issue is because when I try to enable migration it gives the following error which I think is linked back to this.

> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this today too. The solution is here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/

Specifically:

> You can start using EF Core 2.0 today by installing an EF Core
>   2.0-compatible database provider NuGet package in your applications.

The key is "EF Core 2.0-compatible", which means you have to install one of the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` packages from NuGet.

So if you're using SQL Server, you'll install [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/).